# Entity Framework vs NPoco difference and which oneis best?

Tags: entity-framework, npoco

Entity Framework vs NPoco difference and which one is best?

Answer (score 0):

Entity is a feature rich solution and NPoco is a micro solution.  Entity can be slower in some instances because it is doing a whole lot under the covers.  One feature I love is the code first migrations which NPoco will not give you (although I believe there is a nuget package that will give you migrations).  Entity will basically look at your models and create and update your database based on your models and changes.  NPoco, being a micro ORM performs (from what I understand) generally faster than Entity for the few features it offers.